# Store reveal modal cookie in user browser

Tags: jquery, cookies, zurb-foundation, jquery-cookie, zurb-reveal

I am currently using the Zurb foundation framework, I would like to create modal which will appear on page load. I would like this modal to store a cookie in the user browser so that if they have visit the site before they will not be shown the same modal again.

Here is how I attempted to implement this using jQuery which is used initiate foundation. Note I am using the jQuery no conflict wrapper because I am implementing this with word press.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){


$('#myModal2').foundation('reveal', 'open');

 var shown = $.cookie('dialogShown');
      if (!shown) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                  $('#myModal2').foundation({modal: true});
                  $.cookie('dialogShown', 'true');
            }, 2000);





      }});
```

This code is not giving me the desired output, the modal opens on page load over and over again, without storing the cookie, I would really appreciate if anyone could help me out with this. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else is wondering I have posted a solution using the [jQuery cookies](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) plugin.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 if ($.cookie('modal_shown') == null) {
        $.cookie('modal_shown', 'yes', { expires: 7, path: '/' });
        $("#myModal2").foundation('reveal', 'open');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The code you pasted is doing exactly what you have written.

After document ready, opens reveal module (see more: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/v/4.3.2/components/reveal.html )

And after that there is you cookie magic. You have to check for the cookie before you open the modal if you want the behavior described above. :)

Comment: Thank you @pavelloz I am fairly new to javascript, from what i understand I would have to put another if statement in there to check if the modal box has been shown. `if (shown === null) {
          // Do Nothing
    }
   if (jQuery.cookie('reveal')) {
          // Reactions
     }` Am i on the right track?

Comment: jquery-cookie/[js-cookie](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie) returns `undefined` when the cookie is not found. So you need to check against `undefined` instead of `null`. Unless foundation is using a veeery outdated version.

Comment: @steamfunk , write yourself a list of things that program should do (write, not think), example:
1) Check if `shown` cookie is present (IMO no need for specific values, undefined vs anything else should do)
2) If not, show modal
2a) Set cookie
3) If yes, return

If you have a list like that it is much easier to expand it into code.  After some time you will be writing those sentences in pseudo-code, and then in live code. Thats how we learn languages :)